# How to send IMAP - command using java and port 143

Tags: java, tcp, imap

I'm writing imap-mail checker. 
I have something like this :

```
tcpSocket = new Socket();
tcpSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(Config.HOST, 143));
...
// greeting message from server
String answer = socketBufferedReader.readLine();
// try to login
socketBufferedWriter.write("A001 login my_login password\n");
socketBufferedWriter.flush();
// get answer
answer = socketBufferedReader.readLine();
```

In last code's line programm is blocked. and when timeout passes I get answer "*BYE autologout idle for too long".

I can't understand what's wrong. I guess I use wrong format of command but I'm not sure

Comment: Why not using an existing library like [commons-net](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/) instead of writing something from scratch?

Comment: I notice you're terminating your command with `\n` instead of `\r\n` as you should, but that may or may not be the reason for the failure. Perhaps you need to listen for the server's welcome banner (and use it to verify that the type of login you want to use is supported) before you send a command? Also, you should implement STARTTLS because otherwise you're sending the login credentials in the clear. Finally, in order to do all of this properly, I must echo @gma's suggestion to use an existing library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMAP absolutely *requires* the line endings to be \r\n, not just \n.  This goes for a lot of other mail protocols.